# How to disable a childdivider in an ExpandableListView in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to hide child dividers in my ExpandableListView.  I've managed to make the child dividers transparent by adding:

```
<ExpandableListView 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:childDivider="#00000000"/>
```

But it removes the last divider of the current group as well as removing the first divider of the next group.  I want to keep the dividers on both sides of each group, and remove the internal dividers between children.

I'd post an image showing what I'm looking for but this is my first post and it wouldn't let me.  :)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I fixed it.

In the parent groups, I gave them borders on the top so that there was separation between the previous child groups and the current parent group.